# String Replace In PHP

Tags: php, string, replace

i have a long string like

```
$str = "this is [my] test [string] and [string] is very long [with] so many pwords]"
```

i know `str_replace` function, but when i replace

```
$str = str_replace( "[", "<a href=\"/story.php?urdu=",$str;
$str = str_replace( "]", "\"></a>",$str;
```

i got this result

```
<a href="/index.php?word=test"></a>
```

but i want this result for each word in `[]`

```
<a href="/index.php?word=test">test</a>
```

Comment: str_replace function is not closed correctly .

Comment: The example makes no sense. `urdu` != `word`, and your link text should be `my` not `test`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `preg_replace()` for this one.

## Code

```
<?php
    function replace_matches($matches) {
        $text = htmlspecialchars($matches[1]);
        $url = urlencode($matches[1]);
        return "<a href=\"/story.php?urdu={$url}\">{$text}</a>";
    }    
    $str = "this is [my] test [string] and [<script>alert(1)</script>] is very long [with] so many pwords]";
    $str = preg_replace_callback("%\[(.+?)\]%", "replace_matches", $str);

    echo $str;
?>
```

## [Working Example](http://codepad.org/C21eGIag)

Comment: No, you absolutely shouldn't. Why would you invoke a full-blown PCRE replacer if a string search replacer would perform far faster?

Comment: Because a string search replacer wasn't enough?

Comment: How would you suggest doing so? there isn't really something native in PHP to do so, so I'm using regex. Also if "far faster" is around 10ms, I'll take that hit.

Comment: this will not take care of XSS

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = preg_replace_callback(
  '/\[([^\]]*)\]/',
  function($matches) {
    return sprintf('<a href="/index.php?word=%s">%s</a>',
      urlencode($matches[1]),
      htmlspecialchars($matches[1]));
  },
  $str);
```

Comment: @rikudo: what is not working? I wrote the code quickly without testing, but basically it should work

Comment: It's working now (I was missing the pattern delimiters in the regex). the anonymous function callback has to be replaced by `create_function` or a public function in PHP versions prior to 5.3

Comment: also helped me discover a mistake in another answer I've given today :)